# EclipseLink nullable column but unique

Tags: eclipselink, unique, nullable

is it possible to define a column with EclipseLink, which can be null but if a value != null exists, there should only be unique values within the column. How I can model that?

Thank you

Andre

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the value?

I would just enforce the uniqueness in your object model, not in the database.  If you want to restrict it in the database, you could add a check constraint in your own ddl script.

In Java you can use an Enum or just a type code or value and restrict through your set methods.

EclipseLink does have an @ObjectTypeConverter which allows conversion between a set of values.

Comment: The type is String (as Java type). I can not use Enum, it is not a field with a static number of elements. At the moment I get an exception from the database, but it is not possible to recognize the correct problem from the exception description and notify the user interface to display the affected field with a red background color. I have to execute a SELECT just before I insert/update, but this is not multi-user-safe.